# Use string as identifier?

Tags: c++

I have some C++ code like this:

```cpp
struct UpLeft {
    int m_up_left;
};

struct UpRight {
    int m_up_right;
};

struct DownLeft {
    int m_down_left;
};

struct DownRight {
    int m_down_right;
};

struct B {
    UpLeft up_left;
    UpRight up_right;
    DownLeft down_left;
    DownRight down_right;
};

struct A {
    B b;
};

int foo() {
    // some computation, won't always return 0.
    return 0;
}

void setUpLeft(A &a) { a.b.up_left.m_up_left = foo(); }

void setUpRight(A &a) { a.b.up_right.m_up_right = foo(); }

void setDownLeft(A &a) { a.b.down_left.m_down_left = foo(); }

void setDownRight(A &a) { a.b.down_right.m_down_right = foo(); }
```

It is called like this:

```cpp
A a{};
setUpLeft(a);
setUpRight(a);
setDownLeft(a);
setDownRight(a);
```

Instead, I want to delete the set functions and do something like this:

```cpp
// pseudo-code
for (x = {up_left, up_right, down_left, down_right}) {
    a.b.x.x_m = foo();
}
```

So `a.b.x.x_m` becomes `a.b.up_left.up_left_m`, then `a.b.up_right.up_right_m`, etc.

Is there a way to accomplish this in C++?

Comment: it is possible, but it will not be much simpler and requires you write functions very similar to the ones you already have and much more code. If the question is whether C++ can do this out of the box, then no.

Comment: Why not just use aggregate initialization? https://godbolt.org/z/GccvGjvnv

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically you could use pointers to data members, and then apply them to your object you try to modify. A bit simplified example (because yours is extremely superfluous with all these structs holding single ints):

Let's have a structure with 3 membes

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void print(const Foo& f)
{
    std::cout << f.a << ", " << f.b << ", " << f.c << "\n";
}
```

Pointer to `int` member can be defined like this

```
using foo_member_ptr = int Foo::*;
```

and applied like this

```
foo_member_ptr yourPtr = &Foo::a;
obj.*yourPtr = whatever;
```

So, you can define a collection of pointers to members {a, b, c} and collection of expected values, e.g. {4, 5, 6} and then apply them in the loop. Complete example:

```
    Foo foo{1, 2, 3};
    using foo_member_ptr = int Foo::*;
    auto memberPtrList = std::vector<foo_member_ptr>({&Foo::a, &Foo::b, &Foo::c});
    auto nums = std::vector<int>({4, 5, 6});
    print(foo);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        foo.*memberPtrList[i] = nums[i];
    }
    print(foo);
```

But, just because you can do it doesn't necessarily mean that you should. Probably much better approach would be to modify your design and actually use some structure with {key, value} pairs, like `std::unordered_map`. Then your code could become like this:

```
struct B {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> corners;
};
```

and later:

```
b.corners["upperLeft"] = 666;
```